# How can I place a cross-stackexchange website bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

I have a [question on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/is-this-the-proper-way-of-doing-timing-analysis-of-many-test-cases-in-python-or) on which I have placed a bounty because I wasn't getting answers. So far there has been only a single answer on that. I was thinking of asking people on SO for an answer. So I wanted to know how can I place a bounty on SO for the question on codereview. I understand that my rep here will be deducted but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Can anyone point me to the correct place?

---

Asked a [different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189684/if-a-question-can-be-asked-on-multiple-websites-with-a-little-tweaking-what-shou). It might solve the problem.

Comment: What if every high-rep user on Stack Overflow put bounties on Cooking.SE?

Comment: @RobW So what should be done if someone had a question that can be placed on 3 websites with only a little tweaking? Cross-posting?

Comment: One should **not** cross-post on websites.

Comment: @RobW I know that one shouldn't cross-post. That's why I am looking for alternatives. I thought of one and asked how to here. If this isn't possible then maybe I should ask another question about what should be done in this situation.

Comment: @RobW, do you mean that one shouldn't post the same question twice on separate websites, no matter whether the question is relevant to both websites?

Comment: @LeoKing Yes, do not cross-post. If the question is on-topic on both sites, pick the one where you expect to get the most satisfying answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I place a cross-stackexchange website bounty?

You cant.

---

As far as the issue of cross-posting goes, Code Review questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: The question in question has made me confused about which of the 3 sites - SO, programmers, codereview should I place it on. By tweaking the question a bit I think it can be placed on any of these 3. I even asked it on meta codereview [two](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/760/can-this-question-be-improved)  [times](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/766/does-this-question-belong-to-stackoverflow-or-programmers). To avoid cross-posting I thought of this.

Comment: @AseemBansal By changing a question to meet community standards of the relevant site, you can post the same problem again. The only thing that is undesirable is posting the same question, word to word, simultaneously on multiple sites.