# If a question can be asked on multiple websites with a little tweaking what should be done?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, bounties, migration

I had a question that could have been asked on either of these 3 websites - codereview, programmers, codereview with a little tweaking. I decided to post on codereview. So far I got only one answer even after placing a bounty. To get more answers I thought of [placing a cross-SE bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189676/how-can-i-place-a-cross-stackexchange-website-bounty) but it seems that isn't possible or desirable.

So what should be done in case I have such a question? Should I reword the question and request a migration? Should I cross-post? Should I make a feature-request that cross-SE bounties be allowed between these 3 websites? How about [soft-migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration) of questions with some minimum upvotes?

Any suggestions?

This is [the question on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/is-this-the-proper-way-of-doing-timing-analysis-of-many-test-cases-in-python-or).

---

This question isn't specifically about cross-posting. I am asking for alternatives present in this situation

- cross-posting
- cross-SE bounty
- soft-migration
- complete migration

Comment: You should not cross post. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @doubleDown I know that I shouldn't cross-post. That's why I asked it here. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Your use of the words "proper" and "better" make the question too vague to be suitable on Stack Overflow.  We don't know what "proper" and "better" mean from your perspective.  From my perspective, "proper" and "better" always mean "that which best satisfies the software requirements."  Which means we'd have to know what the relevant requirements are to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE sites overlap. This is a fact. So there are many questions that are on-topic on 2 or 3 sites. However, ontopicness is not enough. It's important if there is someone who can answer your question.

There are 2 stereotypical situations, which requires different approach.

1) Your question is on topic on site A, but it's a niche question there. It is also on-topic on site B, but there are a plenty of people asking similar questions. You've just chosen wrong site, through the question is perfectly valid here. In that case you should try migrate the question - flag the moderator with migrate request.

2) You question has received answers, but there are not satisfactory for you, because they concentrate on different aspects as you would like. Those different aspects are usually answered on other site. In that case, you should ask the question on the other site, but rewriting it so, that it would concentrate on those aspects, that were not answered on first site. This is not cross-posting, because it would be 2 different questions.

In 1st case, the problem could occur when the site you want to migrate to is public beta. I've heard that moderators often refuse to migrate questions from mature site to public betas. In that case, I would ask the question anyway, but post on the original's site beta the information about cross posting and ask how to deal with your on-topic but not answered question (close, delete, or leave open with comment about 2nd site).